# How do I clear the selected value from a ComboBox in HeadlessUI

Tags: css, combobox, headless-ui

I'm trying to clear the option that has been selected every time a user opens a combobox.

Currently, when I select an option and open the ComboBox again, the option selected still remains selected.

I've changed the nullable prop to true, but this does not work.

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-chaum-94xsng?file=/src/FilterDropdown.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `open` property from the render function. It tells whether or not the combobox is open. I did this very simple example.

```
<Combobox value={selected} onChange={setSelected} nullable>
  {/* I'm using the open value from the render function
      to set the value to null. When it opens, the value
      is cleared. */}
  {({ open }) => {
    setIsOpen(open);
    if (open) {
      setSelected(null);
    }
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-value-null-after-reopen-9gvhvm) is the full code. Try it out.

Comment: Yes, here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-chaum-94xsng?file=/src/FilterDropdown.js

Comment: @user310737 the FilterDropdown.js component is empty.

Comment: Can you please check again? I have added the code back again.

Comment: I will be honest with you, I could not fully understand you code. To me it seems over-engineering. I could not run the code too, since the it crashes on codebox, but since your questions is  How to clear the value, because it remains selected after you open the combobox again. I will post in my answer a way it works.I think you can get the idea and implement in your code somehow.